# Bulid command for maven

Tags: apache, maven, build

I want to know what is the build command for maven .Including  test cases skip. please help  to solve this problem.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn install -DskipTests` try this command. It includes the test skip part too. This will fix your problem.

`mvn install`  this is the code without test skips

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
mvn clean package install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: This will run the test twice, cause the [lifecycle contains the test phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: `-DskipTests` is often a better choice than `-Dmaven.test.skip` since the former also builds all test cases but don't run them. This will make sure that the code has not introduced breaking changes but as said the tests will not run.

Answer (score 0):

**Building a Project**

```
mvn clean install
mvn clean package
```

**Skip Unit Test**

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test/